# Remove nil values from hash

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I am looking to remove keys from hash that have `nil` value. `article` is a class storing each article, and `attributes` method stores the article as hash.

Expected Result:

```
{"articles":[{"results":[{"author":null,"title":"Former bar manager jailed for preying on homeless 14-year-old girl","summary":"<p><img src=\"http://images.theage.com.au/2015/08/24/6790912/Thumbnail999662740gisd08image.related.thumbnail.320x214.gj68pg.png1440386418031.jpg-90x60.jpg\" width=\"90\" height=\"60\" style=\"float:left;margin:4px;border:0px\"/></p>A man who preyed on a 14-year-old girl he came across living on the streets of&#160;Wodonga has been jailed for nine months.","images":null,"source":null,"date":"Mon, 24 Aug 2015 03:20:21 +0000","guid":"<guid isPermaLink=\"false\">gj68pg</guid>","link":"http://www.theage.com.au/victoria/former-bar-manager-jailed-for-preying-on-homeless-14yearold-girl-20150824-gj68pg.html","section":null,"item_type":null,"updated_date":null,"created_date":null,"material_type_facet":null,"abstract":null,"byline":null,"kicker":null}]}]}
```

Looking to remove null values from the above output.

```
def attributes
  hash = {
    "author" => @author,
    "title" => @title,
    "summary" => @summary,
    "images" => @images,
    "source" => @source,
    "date" => @date
  }
  hash = {}
  count = 0
  article.attributes.each do |key,value|
    if value == nil
      hash[count] = article.attributes.delete(key)
      count += 1
    end
  end
  hash.to_json
```

The result is as below:

```
{"0":null,"1":null,"2":null,"3":null,"4":null,"5":null,"6":null,"7":null,"8":null,"9":null,"10":null}
```

Comment: Please make sure the posted code does run and is complete. I tried to run it and don't see any output at all. Also, the data you mentioned as "expected result" doesn't seem to be part of the code, maybe add a minimal example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: FriendFX - The code is decomposed into a few classes, and it will not be possible to provide that. The second code snippet is where problem lies. The code will not run because there is no article class defined. I am trying to remove keys with no values from article.attributes (storing articles).

Comment: Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some guidance. It seems like your code only deals with a hash (the `article.attributes`?) and you'd like to remove some items, so maybe modify your example such that there are no outside dependencies. Also, I think there is an `end` missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given input is valid JSON, and the question has the JSON tag, so I'd like to offer a generic solution to the problem of recursively eliminating keys in JSON objects, wherever they occur, and no matter what the input JSON may be.

The solution is written in a new JSON-oriented programming language, jq, but even if you cannot use jq, the solution is so brief and elegant that it may suggest an implementation to the general problem in your language of choice.

Here it is - a one-liner:

```
walk( if type == "object" then with_entries( select(.value != null) ) else . end)
```

This presupposes jq version 1.5 (see https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

If you have an older version of jq, the definition of walk/1 can easily be added.  (See e.g. [Transforming the name of key deeper in the JSON structure with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756724/transforming-the-name-of-key-deeper-in-the-json-structure-with-jq))

Answer (score 31):

You can use `compact`.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-compact

Example:

```
hash = {:foo => nil, :bar => "bar"}
=> {:foo=>nil, :bar=>"bar"}
hash.compact
=> {:bar=>"bar"}
hash
=> {:foo=>nil, :bar=>"bar"}
```

There's also `compact!` which removes nil values, or return `nil` if no values in the hash were nil.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-compact-21

Example:

```
hash
=> {:foo=>nil, :bar=>"bar"}
hash.compact!
=> {:bar=>"bar"}
hash
=> {:bar=>"bar"}
hash.compact!
=> nil
```

Comment: Best one so far!

Comment: what is wrong with ruby 2.4.5  or earlier? https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-compact

Comment: @Serge Evidently nothing! I'm guessing when I looked at the version chart for the documentation site I linked when I wrote this I interpreted it to mean it was added in version 2.5.5. I'll update my answer, and thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Updated my comment to link to the docs for what would have been the most recent version of Ruby at the time I originally answered.

Answer (score 11):

How about trying:

```
hash = article.attributes.select {|k, v| v }
```

If the value is `false` or `nil`, the attribute will be ignored.

If you want to keep the false value and only eliminate `nil`, you could run:

```
hash = article.attributes.select {|k, v| !v.nil? }
```

Comment: I forgot `Hash` has a `select` that returns a hash ([Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-select))

Comment: It happens to me all the time. I just assume my issues are common (even when they're not) and spend time searching through the Ruby documentation - I even downloaded an offline version ;-)

Answer (score 8):

You can remove all the `nil` values from a hash namely "h":

```
h.delete_if { |k, v| v.nil? }
```

and you can use this one to remove empty values, too:

```
h.delete_if { |k, v| v.nil? || v.empty? }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I use refinements to Hash class

```
module HashUtil
    refine Hash do
        # simple but can not adapt to nested hash
        def squeeze
            select{|_, v| !v.nil? }
        end
        # complex but can adapt to nested hash
        def squeeze_deep
            each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), squeezed_hash|
                if v.is_a?(Hash)
                    squeezed_hash[k] = v.squeeze
                else
                    squeezed_hash[k] = v unless v.nil?
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

class Article
    using HashUtil
    def attributes
        hash = {
            "author" => @author,
            "title" => @title,
            "summary" => @summary,
            "images" => @images,
            "source" => @source,
            "date" => @date
        }
        hash.squeeze
    end
end
```

Comment: I found simple squeeze is the same as ActiveSupport Hash#compact. Sorry for that. https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/compact