# Ruby remove one nil element from array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got below array of hashes:

```
[{:transaction_date=>nil, :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0},
 {:transaction_date=>nil, :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0},
 {:transaction_date=>nil, :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0},
 {:transaction_date=>"test", :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0}]
```

How to delete key and value od each `transaction_date=>nil` to have something like below:

```
[{:net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0},
 {:net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0},
 {:net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0},
 {:transaction_date=>"test", :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0}]
```

I was trying to use `hash.select { |h| h[:transaction_date] }` but I'm getting only: `[{:transaction_date=>"test", :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0}]` in result. The same for `compact`

Comment: You can use `arr.map {|hash| hash.compact }` or just `arr.map(&:compact)` if you're using ruby >=2.4.6. If not, you can use `arr.map {|hash| hash.select {|_, v| !v.nil? } }`. I would recommend checking the second and third answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174183/remove-nil-values-from-hash) question.

Comment: @Arun, note that it is the key `:transaction_date` that is to be excluded if that key's value is `nil`; it is not to exclude any key whose value is `nil`. True, it is the only key in the example whose value is `nil`, but it would be safest to restrict consideration to that key.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good point. @mr_muscle You might want to use something like `arr.map {|hash| hash.select {|k, v| k != :transaction_date || !v.nil?}}` if you only want to remove the entry where the key is `:transaction_date` and its value is `nil`. 

Thanks for the comment @CarySwoveland!

Comment: Irrelevant question: Is the syntax `{ :key => nil }` equivalent to `{ key: nil }` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove nil values from hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174183/remove-nil-values-from-hash)

Comment: @Fravadona: yes, it is.

Comment: Also note you have not provided a reasoning behind this and it creates an inconsistent data structure in your `Array`. The result of `{:transaction_date=>nil, :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0}[:transaction_date]` and `{:net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0}[:transaction_date]` is identical so I am not certain what the overall use case would be here.

Answer (score 0):

Hashes have a `delete` method which allows a key to be removed.

```rb
a = {"a" => nil, "b" => 2} # => {"a"=>nil, "b"=>2}
a.delete("a") # => nil
a # => {"b"=>2}
```

Then you can use `map` to alter those hashes where your field is nil.

```rb
a = [{:transaction_date=>nil, :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0},
     {:transaction_date=>nil, :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0}, 
     {:transaction_date=>nil, :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0}, 
     {:transaction_date=>"test", :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0}]
a.map do |h|
    h.delete(:transaction_date) if h[:transaction_date].nil?
    h
end # => => [{:net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0}, {:net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0}, {:net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0}, {:transaction_date=>"test", :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0}]
```

Comment: `:transaction_date` will be deleted if `h[:transaction_date] #=> false`, which is not what was asked for. Be specific: `h.delete(:transaction_date) if h[:transaction_date].nil?`! If the original array is not to be mutated use `h.reject { |k,v| k==:transaction_date && v.nil? }`.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, why do you want to remove `:transaction_date` from the hash? I could be wrong but, looks like later on you will end up checking the value of `:transaction_date` regardless, if that's the case, I see no use of getting rid of `:transaction_date`, wasted CPU cycles.

You could simply solve the problem by doing the following in the places you need to access `h[:transaction_date]`

```
if h[:transaction_date]
  # print/save/manipulate date
end
```

why? because if `h[:transaction_date]` doesn't exist in the hash, you will get `nil` anyways when you try to access it later on (unless you have a default value).

---

`Array#select` returns a new array only with the elements that fits the criteria of the block. If the block returns something falsy, the element that was passed to the block will be discarded.

That means you can't use `Array#select` effectively here, since your elements are hashes and the result you want involve the keys of each hash.

`Array#compact` returns a new array with all nil elements removed. Again this only works at the array level, doesn't touch the elements.

The operations you were trying to do are related to the array itself and not the elements of the array.

What you need is to inspect each element of the array and modify them according to the criteria you have.

There are many ways of doing this, probably not the best but this one is one way:

```
arr.each do|h|
  if h[:transaction_date].nil?
    h.delete(:transaction_date)
  end
end

puts arr
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple and short solution for remove key from has if the value is nil

```
has_data = [{:transaction_date=>nil, :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0},
 {:transaction_date=>nil, :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0},
 {:transaction_date=>nil, :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0},
 {:transaction_date=>"test", :net_amount=>100.0, :vat=>0.0}]

**has_data.each{|a| a.compact!}**
```

Answer (score 0):

If only `transaction_date` is nullable, you can just `array_hash.map(&:compact)`